# Solving errors when populating data to bootstrap modal after using ajax request

Tags: jquery

I am using bootstrap modal to display data dynamically once a button is clicked. The button collects data from the database and it goes to the ajax request which sends the data to the page with the modal. The data is sent well but the modal shows an error:

> parsererror:SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data:

What can I do?

```
<script>
    function detailsmodal(Productid) {
        var data = {"Productid": Productid};
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/project/includes/modalbody.php',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                jQuery('.modal-body').append(data);
                jQuery('#details-modal').modal('toggle');
            }
        }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert('error:' + status + ':' + error + ':' + xhr.responseText)
        }).always(function () {
            location.reload();
        });
    }
 </script>
```

**modalbody.php**

```
<?php
require_once '../includes/init.php';
$id = $_POST['Productid'];
$id = (int)$id;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Productid = '$id'";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$brand_id = $product['Brand'];
$sql = "SELECT Brand FROM Brand WHERE Brandid = '$brand_id'";
$brand_query = $db->query($sql);
$brand = mysqli_fetch_assoc($brand_query);
$sizestring = $product['Size'];
//$sizestring = ($sizestring,',');
$size_array = explode(',' , $sizestring);
?>
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<div class="modal fade detail-1" id="details-modal"          tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detail-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <!--***CLOSING MODAL CLASS****-->
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"   onclick="closeModal()">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">
                    <?php echo $product['Name']; ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <span id="modal_errors" class="bg-danger"></span>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="center-block">
                                <img src="
<?php echo $product['Image'];?>" alt="
<?php echo  $product['Name'];?>" class="img-fluid"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h3>
                                Details
                            </h3>
                            <p>
                                <?php echo nl2br($product['Description']); ?></p>
                            <p>
                                Price: Ksh.
                                <?php echo $product['UnitPrice']; ?></p>
                            <p>
                                Brand: 
                                <?php echo $brand['Brand']; ?></p>
                            <form action="add_cart.php" method="POST" id="add_product_form">
                                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="
<?php echo$id;?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="available" id="available" value="">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-group" id="quantity"  name="quantity" min="0">
                                    <br/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="size">Size:</label>
                                    <select name="size" id="size" name="size" class="form-control">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <?php foreach($size_array as $string){
    $string_array = explode(':', $string);
    $size = $string_array[0];
    $available = $string_array[1];
    echo '<option value="'.$size.'" data-available="'.$available.'">'.$size.' (Available: '.$available.')</option>';
}?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="height:90px;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"  onclick="closeModal()" style="margin-top:0px;">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="add_to_cart();return false;" style="margin-top:0px;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart">Add To Cart</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    //event listener
    jQuery('#size').change(function(){
        var available = jQuery('#size   option:selected').data("available");
        jQuery('#available').val(available);
    }
                          );
    function closeModal(){
        jQuery('#details-modal').modal('hide');
        setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery('#details-modal').remove();
            jQuery('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        }
                   ,500);
    }
</script>
<?php echo ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

Comment: What does return when you do a `echo json_encode($data);` are you returning an HTML code or just a JSON Object?

Comment: Is the echo json_encode($data) supposed to be in the detailsmodal function or the modalbody.php page?

Comment: On the .php file, this is to see if you're returning a valid JSON

Comment: It is receiving a JSON Object

Comment: are you sure that's your echo json_encode($data)? Or it's just your code of the modal?

Comment: The echo json_encode($data) will show an integer which is the productid but when the modal pops up it show the code

Comment: Ok this going nowhere does `json_encode()` return something like: `{"productid":1}`? if not your json is wrong, more over for how you're doing an append it seems that you are actually returning HTML and not a JSON data

Comment: I have checked through the chrome developer tool the Form data is Productid : 1 and the json_encode displays the same integer once I click on the same product

Comment: Ok seem like I haven't asked the right question, when I said `$data ` I mean the data that you're returning on your php not the product id you're sending, we want to know exactly what is being returning, something like a list of products etc.

Comment: The php receives the product id and based on the product id it will display its respectful information from that fetched from the database. Could you please clarify on the part of returning HTML and JSON data and how to approach both of them.

Comment: Can you add the .php that you're returning, what I mean is it's information response of your .php

Comment: The phpis in the updated code above

Answer (score 0):

**Ajax with  Json**

```
<script>
    function detailsmodal(Productid_value) {
    var str = {Productid: Productid_value};
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/project/includes/modalbody.php",
        data: str,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
            var respons = response;
            //var type = respons.status
            jQuery('.modal-body').append(respons.Productid);
            jQuery('#details-modal').modal('toggle');
        }
    }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert('error:' + status + ':' + error + ':' + xhr.responseText)
    }).always(function () {
        location.reload();
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: With the use of JSON.stringify() there is an undefined index of of the data I initialized that was sent via ajax request and the Syntax error is still present

Comment: The code is very helpful whereby the Productid is received successfully in the modalbody.php page but the bootstrap modal pops up with the code i.e 
          <

Comment: The code is very helpful whereby the Productid is received successfully in the modalbody.php page but the bootstrap modal pops up with the code and not the actual buttons i.e 
         error:parsererror:SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character 
         at line 2 column 3 of the JSON data:
         <div class="modal fade detail-1" id="details-modal" tabindex="-1" 
         role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detail-1" aria-hidden="true">  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">

Answer (score 0):

Seem like what you're returning is actually an HTML and not a JSON change your Ajax

`dataType: 'json',` to  `dataType: 'HTML',` you can also try with `dataType: 'text',`

That should work as what it seems in your code you are doing an `.append()` that is going to include your HTML response

Comment: The answer is very helpful but the output displayed on the browser is the actual HTML 'snippet' with tags of the bootstrap modal. Is there a way this can be processed so as not to show the actual code but user-friendly information?

Comment: Could there be another alternative of actually sending the data to the bootstrap modal?

Comment: Sorry for the late response well basically yes, get your info and return it as formated JSON and then setting that data in the input, that would be a good way

Comment: I've never used the ajax request so could you specify on what you mean by the last answer you have given